# How to add javascript to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Today i was trying to add this to html file but don't work

```
<head><script>$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 46) {
        if (val.replace(/\s/g, '').length % 4 == 0) {
            $(this).val(val + ' ');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).val(val);        
    }
})</head></script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="textbox">
</body>
```

Can anyone help me? thanks anyway

Comment: you have to include jquery to your html file as well

Comment: Please include *why* it doesn't work. What errors are you seeing? I do suspect @JoshuaK is correct though.

Comment: debugging 101: all good browsers have a **developer** tools console, usually you get to it using F12 - info/warnings/errors on that console go a long way to finding out where your code is failing, so either you can fix it, or ask for help with more than just the very redundant "it doesn't work" - if it worked, you wouldn't be asking, right :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You need to include a reference to JQuery.
2. The `<script>` requires `#textbox` in the DOM for it to subscribe to keyup event. Hence the script should be placed at the end of the body. This way `#textbox` is added to DOM by the time the script runs.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="textbox">

  <script>
    $('#textbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
      var val = this.value;
      
      if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 46) {
        if (val.replace(/\s/g, '').length % 4 == 0) {
          $(this).val(val + ' ');
        }
      } else {
        $(this).val(val);
      }
    })
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

`<head>` and `<script>` close in a wrong order

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>

    <script>$('#textbox').on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 46) {
        if (val.replace(/\s/g, '').length % 4 == 0) {
            $(this).val(val + ' ');
        }
    } else {
        $(this).val(val);        
    }
})
</script>

</head>

<body>
   <input type="text" id="textbox">
</body>
```

The above code will work. You need to add the `<script>` tag before `</head>` that was the problem. Check this out for more information [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp).

It's good practice to write script in the `<body></body>` and you need to insert jQuery CDN in the `<head></head>` if you want to use jQuery.